# RN bridge for Swift Augmented Reality SDK

Tags: react-native

I'm interested in building an iOS app that will incorporate a native third-party AR library (either ARToolkit or Vuforia). At this point I am evaluating native vs RN as a path of least resistance. Either option would involve learning new tools/frameworks, but as someone with a background in web dev I'd prefer to tap into that pool of experience rather than going full native.

My dilemma at this moment is that I'm not familiar with the limitations/difficulties of RN bridges. Would it even be possible to create a Swift bridge between RN and a third-party AR library ? Or would I be better off sticking to native development for something like this when heavier image processing is involved?

Thanks in advance.